# Relevance the search result in Lucene

Tags: c#-4.0, lucene.net

**What I want is :**

In the search method i will add an extra parameter say relevance param of type float to setup the cuttoff relevance. So lets say if the cutoff is 60% I want items that are higher than 60% relevance.

Here is current code of search :

say the search text is a
and in lucene file system i have following description:
1) abcdef
2)abc
3)abcd

**for now it will fetch all the above three docuements , i want to fetch those which are that are higher than 60% relevance.**

//for now i am not using the relevanceparam anywhere in the method :

```
public static string[] Search(string searchText,float relevanceparam)
        {
            //List of ID
            List<string> searchResultID = new List<string>();

            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
            Term searchTerm = new Term("Text", searchText);
            Query query = new TermQuery(searchTerm);
            Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++)
            {
                float r = hits.Score(i);
                Document doc = hits.Doc(i);

                searchResultID.Add(doc.Get("ID"));
            }
            return searchResultID.ToArray();
        }
```

**Edit :**

what if i set boost to my query 
say :  query.SetBoost(1.6);-- is this is equivalent to 60 percent?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by ignore those hits that have less than a `TopDocs.MaxScore * minRelativeRelevance` where `minRelativeRelevance` should be a value between 0 and 1.

I've modified your code to match the 3.0.3 release of Lucene.Net, and added a FieldSelector to your call to `IndexSearcher.Doc` to avoid loading non-required fields.

Calling `Query.SetBoost(1.6)` would only mean that the score calculated by that query would be boosted by 60% (multiplied with 1.6). It may change the ordering of the result if there were other queries involved (in a BooleanQuery, for example), but it wont change which results are returned.

```
public static String[] Search(IndexReader reader, String searchText, 
                              Single minRelativeRelevance) {
    var resultIds = new List<String>();

    var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    var searchTerm = new Term("Text", searchText);
    var query = new TermQuery(searchTerm);
    var hits = searcher.Search(query, 100);

    var minScore = hits.MaxScore * minRelativeRelevance;
    var fieldSelector = new MapFieldSelector("ID");
    foreach (var hit in hits.ScoreDocs) {
        if (hit.Score >= minScore) {
            var document = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc, fieldSelector);
            var hitId = document.Get("ID");
            resultIds.Add(hitId);
        }
    }

    return resultIds.ToArray();
}
```